# ::before and invisible background-image

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a navigation with images left and right as a hover effect (see picture [navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX1BZ.png) ).

I have this code:

HTML

```
<nav class="clearfix"> 
<ul class="clearfix">
<li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
<li><a href="#get_involved">get involved</a></li>
<li><a href="#kenia2016">kenia 2016</a></li>
<li><a href="#projects">projects</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav a:hover::before {
    content: "____";
    background: url('../img/mosterdseed_left.png') no-repeat;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

When I remove the content property in the CSS, the image becomes invisible. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Just write `content: "";`

You'll have 'empty' content then. You need to add the content property for the ::before and ::after pseudo elements to become visible, but it is allowed to be an empty string.

But by default ::before and ::after are inline elements, and they will ignore width and height. It will work as soon as you position them absolutely.

Below is a snippet that shows what you need to add to make it work.

```css
nav a {
    /* To be able to absolutely possition the pseudo elements inside the link. */
    position: relative;
}

nav a:hover::before {
    background: url('../img/mosterdseed_left.png') no-repeat;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    
    /* To make the pseudo element visible in the first place. */
    content: "";

    /* To position the image */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  
    /* To make it visible, since the image cannot be loaded in the example */
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<nav class="clearfix"> 
<ul class="clearfix">
<li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
<li><a href="#get_involved">get involved</a></li>
<li><a href="#kenia2016">kenia 2016</a></li>
<li><a href="#projects">projects</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: thx for your help. I tried, but it resulted in an invisible background-image.